# Enable control panel access to site admin in liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet

I want to enable the control panel access rights to site admin default role.  Where do I found related class / source files to edit the site admin permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make changes in source code for this feature. In Liferay site-admin role do have control-panel access for the site-admin-functionality.

Comment: I didn't find. Can you guide me the steps for the same please

Comment: --> Assign site-membership to any user
--> Assign site-admin role to the same user
--> Log-in to the portal with the user
--> From the Dockbar --> click on "Admin" --> "Site Administration"